# My SQL query is showing no rows returned error

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL, I tried to dump all data from a table by using

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'table_name;
```

but it says 'NO rows returned'

But when I try to fetch column name from the same table by

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

it shows all the column names available in the same table

So the question is there any way to get all the database available in the table?

Comment: Your table is empty simple, there is now rows in it. Therefore, there is nothing to dump.

Comment: run `SELECT COUNT(*) as numb FROM 'table_name';` and see what it gives you; if it gives you a number zero then as mentioned above, your table is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM 'table_name;

This query is returning empty because your table is empty.

If you want to fetch particular column, use below query.

SELECT column_name FROM table_name;